# Integrity error when trying to save twice the same object using save_formset

Tags: django, django-admin

I am out of ideas and I need some help about a problem that I encounter when I try to save the same object. Let me explain.

I have a model, let's call it **Pizza**. And **Topping** which has a foreign key to **Pizza**:

I have implemented an Admin view **PizzaAdmin** and I have added a tabular inline of **Topping**

so from PizzaAdmin, I can add several toppings.

I have override the **save_formset** method where I call a helper to perform a third-party API call.
From the API response, I need to save some data to my toppings.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    super(PizzaAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)

    helper = ApiHelper(instance=form.instance)
    helper.sync()
```

This helper makes a call to an API, parse the response and associate an ID for each toppings of Pizza.

```
class ApiHelper(...):
    def sync(self):
        # parse response

        for topping in self.instance.toppings.all():
            if ....:
                topping.some_id = ...
                topping.save()
```

When I reach the `topping.save()`, I got this error: `IntegrityError`

I do not want to create a new **Topping** but update its property `some_id`.

After futher investigation, I realised that `save_formset` is called by `save_related` which is called by `changeform_view` which as the decorator `@transaction.atomic`

Is there a way to force the commit inside an atomic transaction ?

Please advise. Thanks a lot.

***** UPDATE: 2017-03-30 *****

I have found [transaction.on_commit()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) which allows me to perform actions after the commit:

```
class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super(PizzaAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)    
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: sync_toppings(instance=form.instance))


def sync_toppings(instance):
    helper = ApiHelper(instance=form.instance)
    helper.sync()
```

Inside **sync()** method, I have replace my queryset using this logic:

```
toppings_qs = Topping.objects.filter(pizza=self.instance)
```

I still have an **IntegrityError** when I try to *update* the topping through the queryset.

I do not understand why. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake!!!
This is what I did:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.is_negative = True
    super(Topping, self).save(self, **kwargs)
```

Notice the **self** in save of the super() :(

My fix:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.is_negative = True
    super(Topping, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```